# Equation for: How does Thickness of Aluminum Pipe affect the velocity of the magnet falling through?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I need help in finding the equation for how the velocity of a magnet dropped through an aluminum foil pipe is affected when the thickness of the pipe is changed. Thank You.

Comment: Two colleagues did this: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263663101_A_quasi-static_electromagnetic_analysis_for_experiments_with_strong_permanent_magnets

Answer (score 2):

An exact equation would require an exact description of the shape, strength, orientation of the magnet. But generally, we can say the thicker the walls, the slower the fall. This is because the electrical resistance of the walls is less, the thicker they are.

Comment: Re, "...because the electrical resistance...is less."  The Voltage per unit length in the circuit is going to be approximately proportional to the speed of the falling magnet, and the current is going to be proportional to the force that the current loop exerts on the magnet.  So, I'm pretty sure that, using Ohm's Law, you should be able to prove that when the system is in equillibrium (electric force == force of gravity), the speed at which the magnet falls should be inversely proportional to the resistance of the loop.  Except..., there may be some detail I'm missing... uh...

Comment: ...because if what I just said was true, and if you made the tube of superconducting material, then the magnet should just hang there forever, and that doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: @Solomon Slow what would you say this equation is? Would  = *v/ be a reasonable equation to calculate the effect of thickness on the velocity if:  = magnetic field of the magnet,  = velocity of the magnet, =cross
sectional area, and   = resistivity?

Comment: @Digiproc I am aware that increasing the thickness will reduce the velocity of the magnet. Do you know the equation which can be used to further represent this?

Comment: @FLUX, Sorry, I am not a physicist, which is why I did not attempt an actual answer to your question.